# Android Studio(2.1.2) strange error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error since I updated the **android studio** from *2.1.1 to 2.1.2*.
   I am trying to build my project and get this strange error (all worked perfectly in previous AS versions)

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Consts;
```

Some other problems also comes with it.Myanother problem also come after update android studio from *2.1.1 to 2.1.2*.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: Are you using `multiDexEnabled true` ? Have you tried Java 8 SDK? (I would, even if you code in Java 1.7)

Comment: ok thanks@MartínMarconcini